# Problems with editing using a custom model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have this data model:

```
public class User
    {
        public long UserID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User name is required.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "User name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Email]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]        
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]        
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Full name cannot be longer than 150 characters.")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public int UserTypeID { get; set; }

        public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    }
```

and I'm using this model to only edit some fields (password shouldn't be editable):

```
public class EditUserModel
    {
        public long UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Email]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Full name")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Full name cannot be longer than 150 characters.")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public int UserTypeID { get; set; }

        public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
    }
```

but I'm confused on how to pass the EditUserModel to my data context to update it. Sorry if seems elementary, but I'm really stumped.

This is the auto-generated edit action that I modified:

```
[IsAdministrator]
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditUserModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.UserTypeID = new SelectList(db.UserTypes, "UserTypeId", "Name", user.UserTypeID);
            return View(user);
        }
```

This is the line I'm having trouble with:

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

The reason I created a custom class was to avoid exposing the password from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work because you're trying to save view model.

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to rewrite data from view model to your data model. After that you should be able to save changes.

```
User userModel = Mapper.Map<EditUserModel, User>(user);
userModel = // todo: get password from database
// todo: attach your model to context and save changes
```

I'm using Entity Framework Code First and that approach works great.

Comment: Thanks, but is there another way without having to download Automapper?

Comment: You can get user object from db context and rewrite values from view model.

Comment: I tried that but db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; will not work with my view model.

Comment: I mean something like this `var userModel = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id); userModel.UserName = user.UserName;
...`

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean because I already that, but saving it to my context will not work, since being a view model, I did not define it within my context.

Comment: Marking your answer as the solution because it gave me an idea on how to solve it on my own. Thanks.